# Python: For each list element apply a function across the list

Tags: python, algorithm, list, list-comprehension

Given `[1,2,3,4,5]`, how can I do something like

```
1/1, 1/2, 1/3,1/4,1/5, ...., 3/1,3/2,3/3,3/4,3/5,.... 5/1,5/2,5/3,5/4,5/5
```

I would like to store all the results, find the minimum, and return the two numbers used to find the minimum. So in the case I've described above I would like to return `(1,5)`.

So basically I would like to do something like

for each element `i` in the list
map some function across all elements in the list, taking `i` and `j` as parameters
store the result in a master list, find the minimum value in the master list, and return the arguments `i`, `j`used to calculate this minimum value.

In my real problem I have a list objects/coordinates, and the function I am using takes two coordinates and calculates the euclidean distance. I'm trying to find minimum euclidean distance between any two points but I don't need a fancy algorithm.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can do this using [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [min()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html) (Python 3.0 code):

```
>>> nums = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> [(x,y) for x in nums for y in nums]
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5), (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3), (4, 4), (4, 5), (5, 1), (5, 2), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5)]
>>> min(_, key=lambda pair: pair[0]/pair[1])
(1, 5)
```

Note that to run this on Python 2.5 you'll need to either make one of the arguments a float, or do `from __future__ import division` so that 1/5 correctly equals 0.2 instead of 0.

Comment: Note that the 'key' argument to min is only accepted since 2.5

Comment: I would have used zip(nums, nums) instead of the listcomp, but otherwise that would have been my solution.

Comment: Actually, zip(nums, nums) results in [(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 5)], which is not correct.

Comment: For a better use of memory, instead of a list, you can use a generator:

nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
pairs = ((x, y) for x in nums for y in nums)
m = min(pairs, key=lambda pair: pair[0] / pair[1])

Thus, each pair is generated sequentially, which is more memory-efficient than keeping a list of pairs.

Comment: For those wondering about the single underscore in the posted code: [What is the purpose of the single underscore “_” variable in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5893163/1025391)

Answer (score 10):

If I'm correct in thinking that you want to find the minimum value of a function for all possible pairs of 2 elements from a list...

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5]

def f(i,j):
   return i+j 

# Prints min value of f(i,j) along with i and j
print min( (f(i,j),i,j) for i in l for j in l)
```

Comment: Lists named "l" freak me out a little bit. Good solution though :)

Comment: Yeah, I always call my generic lists 'lst'.

Comment: I'd add a [1:] at the end: print min( (1.*i/j,i,j) for i in l for j in l)[1:]

Comment: Thought about it, but it felt much less readable to me @Andrea

Comment: @Triptych: the 1.*i/j or the [1:] ?!?

Comment: @Andreas, the [1:].  I abstracted out the division to make it clear that any function could be there.

Answer (score 3):

Some readable python:

```
def JoeCalimar(l):
    masterList = []
    for i in l:
        for j in l:
            masterList.append(1.*i/j)
    pos = masterList.index(min(masterList))
    a = pos/len(masterList)
    b = pos%len(masterList)
    return (l[a],l[b])
```

Let me know if something is not clear.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind importing the numpy package, it has a lot of convenient functionality built in.  It's likely to be much more efficient to use their data structures than lists of lists, etc.

```
from __future__ import division

import numpy

data = numpy.asarray([1,2,3,4,5])
dists = data.reshape((1,5)) / data.reshape((5,1))

print dists

which = dists.argmin()
(r,c) = (which // 5, which % 5) # assumes C ordering

# pick whichever is most appropriate for you...
minval = dists[r,c]
minval = dists.min()
minval = dists.ravel()[which]
```

Answer (score 1):

Doing it the mathy way...

```
nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
min_combo = (min(nums), max(nums))
```

Unless, of course, you have negatives in there.  In that case, this won't work because you actually want the min and max absolute values - the numerator should be close to zero, and the denominator far from it, in either direction.  And double negatives would break it.

Comment: BTW, Does not do what the question asks. Yes, it is the solution to the simple example in the question, but it does not say how to apply some function to pairs of numbers. (Or perhaps the question was improved after this answer was posted.)

Answer (score 1):

If working with Python ≥2.6 (including 3.x), you can:

```
from __future__ import division
import operator, itertools

def getmin(alist):
    return min(
        (operator.div(*pair), pair)
        for pair in itertools.product(alist, repeat=2)
    )[1]

getmin([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

EDIT: Now that I think of it and if I remember my mathematics correctly, this should also give the answer assuming that all numbers are non-negative:

```
def getmin(alist):
    return min(alist), max(alist)
```

Comment: If the OP wants to calculate euclidean distance, there's itertools.combinations generator which will yield only unique pairs of different values from input.

Comment: @liori: the OP does not seem to want euclidean distances. Thanks for your comment, anyway, since it reminded me of the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]    
>>> min(map((lambda t: ((float(t[0])/t[1]), t)), ((x, y) for x in nums for y in nums)))[1]
(1, 5)
```